# What do I need to enter Taiwan?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, pakistani-citizens, taiwan

I'm a Pakistani citizen, in Malaysia as a tourist, and I want to go to Taiwan, also for tourism. Is it possible? Do I need a visa and could I get one in Malaysia?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=pk&DE=tw&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with an ROC (Taiwan)
>   Business and Academic Travel Card issued by Chinese Taipei for
>   a maximum stay of 30 days

So yes, you need a visa, which you may be able to apply for at the Consular Division of the *de facto* ROC embassy in Kuala Lumpur. The address is:

> Level 7, Menara Yayasan Tun Razak, 200 Jalan Bukit Bintang, 55100 Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia